# Number of Objects created when initiating an array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am studying for the Java OCA exam and I encounter a problem. Given the following code, how many objects are created? Authors of the book say 5, while I say 3. Why 3? because 2 objects of type dozens are created and the 3rd object being the array itself. Rest of array elements are null, so we only create references, but not objects in my opinion. I have added a print in the constructor which prints twice. Is there something that I am missing or the answer provided in the book is wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
class Dozens {
    int[] dz = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

    public Dozens(){
        System.out.println("Object created");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dozens[] da = new Dozens[3];
        da[0] = new Dozens();
        Dozens d = new Dozens();
        da[1] = d;
        d = null;
        da[1] = null;
        // do stuff
        System.out.println(da[2] instanceof Object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Five objects will be created explicitly by the execution of the `main` method.

- One `Dozens[]` object
- Two `Dozens` objects
- Two `int[]` objects; see the `dz` field.

In addition, some objects *may* be created behind the scenes by the `println` call(s).

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake, each dozen object have an array field, so every time a dozen object is created there are 2 objects created.